# How to move down the camera view after click on marker google maps sdk

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

I already know how to move the camera to a certain point(LatLng) but what I want is if I click on the marker, the camera moves a little bit down from the center.

The initial position I use :

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,14));
```

and I add the marker position :

```
marker.setPosition(new LatLng(-8.160727, -34.915348));
```

Whe  I click it centralized the marker with the Title. The only way that I know to move the camera is passing a LatLng position.

This is the default :

[image]

And how I want :

[image]